# Hiding bottom line in QTabBar

Tags: qt, user-interface, tabs, qt4, qtabbar

There doesn't seem to be a way of setting a stylesheet for the bottom line (shown in the image below) of a `QTabBar`, which I want to be removed.

[image: bottom line of the `QTabBar shown]

How can I remove it?

Comment: Having the same issue, how did you actually do it (removed the line?)

Comment: i'dont remember, but it seems i just used QTabBar::setDrawBase(false)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haven't used Qt in 6-7 months now so I'm not sure if this will work nor can I test it. Give [`QTabBar::drawBase`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html#drawBase-prop) a try. Plus the Qt library are very well documents so you should find a solution to your problems if you just carefully sift through it.

Hope you are using the [Qt SDK](http://qt-project.org/downloads).