# Qt stylesheet weird line on top of tab bar

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtstylesheets

I style my QTabWidget and got a weird line on top of the tab bar. It only happens when it has multi tabs.

```
QTabWidget::pane {
    border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    top: -1px;
}

QTabWidget::tab-bar {
    left: 5px;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Any advice to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: The -1px in the pane looks suspicous. Why do you need that?

Comment: If not, the selected tab will have a bottom line and that's not good looking.

Comment: ... just in case somebody ends up here... (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458431/hiding-bottom-line-in-qtabbar)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to turn off the base in the `QTabBar`:

```
QTabBar {
    qproperty-drawBase: 0;
}
```

Comment: FINALLY! God I spent way too long trying to figure this out with qss (I have a ton of styling going on in this app).